# Why would a web site keep my signup information for a limited time only?

Tags: registration

I have just created account at (some web service, well, actually it was [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/), a localization service).  Registration form requested typical things: accont name, e-mail adress, password (twice), and, optional company name and phone number.

What confused me was this sentence on confirmation page (the one right after submitting the form):

> We will store your signup information for 7 days on our server.

Can anybody explain what does this mean?

What exactly they are referring to by "signup information", if it's something that should be kept for only 7 days?  Or is my account going to be destroyed after that time?  (Well, that could make sense for some special services, but not for this one.)

Comment: Perhaps it means your IP address and user-agent.

Comment: I see they have live support, have you tried contacting the service directly?

Comment: Do they require any kind of account activation or validation? Maybe they're saying if your account isn't activated / validated within 7 days, they won't continue to store your information and you'll have to re-register and validate.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably caching your information so the information you used to sign-up will be reserved until you activate the account, prior to that date they will block anyone who attempts to sign-up with the exact information. An example is email address, websites will block people from having multiple accounts linking to one email address.

Answer (score 1):

That simply means after signing up with that website you'll be getting a verification e-mail, so if you did not activated your account in 7 days they will remove your information and account will be disabled, I had a live chat with one of their employee, you can try doing same.

Just for your info :

> →Why would your web site keep my signup information for a limited time only?
>
> →"We will store your signup information for 7 days on our server."
>   what does this means?
>
> Ratnadeep: An activation link has been mailed to you
>
> Ratnadeep: please click that link to activate your account →that means
>   if i didnt activated that link you'll remove my info?
>
> Ratnadeep: it will not be removed
>
> Ratnadeep: it will be disabled
>
> →ok thnks :)